# Monitoring Clients Screen on wireless network on win7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, monitoring, remote-control

I'm already using "Netsupport Manager" to access and monitor my clients (about 12 windows 7 machines) , when i connect to a client using netsupport manager it change windows 7 theme to "Windows Seven Basic Theme" and Changes background to black . 
my boss want to monitor clients screen without noticing them , but i can't do it with NSP.

I need software that :

1-Monitor Screens in silent (Sending screenshots or all monitors in thumbnail is good)

2-Work well on my wireless network (54Mbps,  so sacrificing fps is ok )

3-Having remote control feature in needed situations

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Net Support Manager (and the education alternative, Net Support School, and Ranger) are good products but this is a problem for us as well. Shy of setting all clents to Windows 7 Basic and a black desktop you could either contact Net Support to see if they have a answer or see if you can use a VNC flavour to roll out to your network. They can be connected to directly or use some monitering application t show the screens in a grid view.